# RSSI measurement tool for RFID tag

Tags: microcontroller, rfid

I am building a prototype to measure the RSSI strength of RFID tags to get the signal strength. I tried looking for different kinds of readers but they only measure the presence of RFID tags but not differentiate between signal strength. Is there any tool or microcontroller or software through which I can measure the signal strength of RFID tags?

Comment: Yes, you could use a spectrum analyser with a suitable antenna. Tune the spectrum analyser to the desired frequency, hook up the antenna and measure the signal level at a fixed distance, say 50cm.

Comment: is there any software/ide based on RFID that can measure it maybe using any external devices? I saw it on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWzyPZAPbt0 at 10:45 but not able to guess/identify what is it.

Comment: First of all passive RFID tags (presumably what you are referring to) are passive and are powered by the Transmitter's EM energy. So then you are really wanting to  measure the transmitter's field strength at a certain distance ? If there is any confusion about your intended measurements then I suggest you read up on the types of RFID tags like here https://lowrysolutions.com/blog/a-guide-to-understanding-uhf-passive-rfid-antennas/#:~:text=The%20UHF%20passive%20RFID%20antenna,attribute%20data%20from%20the%20chip.

Comment: yes, I am referring to passive RFID tags. More specifically I am trying to measure the strength of UHF passive RFID tags. I am trying to measure the RSSI strength of the reflected wave by the tag at a certain distance.

Comment: You might find your answer over here : https://community.st.com/t5/st25-nfc-rfid-tags-and-readers/how-to-measure-rssi-on-nfc-reader-and-tag/td-p/144384 They may have suitable development board specifically for RFID applications in the UHF band.